# set up 2 wifi router with same SSID

Tags: wireless-networking

Trying to set up linksys and medialink routers so that they have same ssid and same security credentials.

From my cable modem, I am connecting to my linksys [primary router].

linksys set up on 192.168.0.100

ip range from > .102

medialink[secondary] set up 192.168.0.101, dhcp disabled

I also have trendnet print server set up on 192.168.0.1.

I set up the routers 1 by 1, then connected linksys to meidalink and powered it up.

I can see my AP on both routers, I made my secondary router to have no security, however when I try connecting on my open ssis [on medialink] I get no connection and somehow it kills the network in the sense that I cannot connect to my linksys without powering down both routers.

Not doing this via DD-WRT.

I am unsure where the flaw is in the set up.

Comment: Is the cable modem also a router or is it bridging? Are the two wifi routers connected LAN-to-LAN? What's connected to their WAN/Internet ports, if anything?

Comment: The cable modem is not bridging. THink comcast do not brdige their modems by default

Comment: The security on both routers is identical, right? Same SSID, same security type, same password? They're connected LAN-to-LAN, not WAN-to-LAN?

Comment: @user266356 If the cable modem is not bridging, why do you have DHCP set up on either router? Are you intentionally trying to set up double NAT?

Comment: What's your IP set-up on the MediaLink? Gateway, etc?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I followed a guide online and that was the recommendation. The 2 routers are connected cable modem to linksys wan. linksys lan to medialink wan. Media link is set up on 192.168.0.101, gateway 192.168.0.100[this happens to be ip of the linksys]

Comment: @user266356 Do you have a link to this guide? I'm curious if it's crap or if you misunderstood it.

Comment: @user266356 You definitely need to connect the two routers LAN-to-LAN. Here's a guide: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ConfiguringTwoWirelessRoutersWithOneSSIDNetworkNameAtHomeForFreeRoaming.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can't have both routers numbered inside the same network but connected WAN-to-LAN. Either they're in the same network or they're not, you can't have half and half.

Change the router-to-router link to LAN-to-LAN instead of LAN-to-WAN. This will still give you a poor setup with double NAT, but at least it will mostly work instead of mostly not working.

Ideally, you'd switch either the cable modem or the other wifi router to just bridging. That way, you have no ugly double NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Having a router behind another router is Bad News, for normally routers also provide other services such as DHCP. Make sure to bridge the second router so it just acts as a WAP and a switch. Me, I'd just get a wifi repeater which would require no extra management at all.

Comment: Using a WiFi repeater would provide about 1/3 the bandwidth of two APs wired to each other. That would be the last choice if you had no other way to increase range.

Comment: David's absolutely correct, if you can run an Ethernet cable from one to the other, that's superior to using a repeater.